# Casting query .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, casting

Can someone please explain why this works:

```
RibbonTab rt_selecteda = (RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem;
string a = rt_selecteda.Tag.ToString();
```

but this fails:

```
string ab = (RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString();
```

'object' does not contain a definition for 'Tag' and no extension method 'Tag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) W:\Dev_Code\Reporting_App\Core\Ribbon_Common.cs 114 78  Reporting_App

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
string ab = (RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString();
```

is not the same as (note the brackets)

```
string ab = ((RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
```

which is the one-line equivalent to your first code

```
RibbonTab rt_selecteda = (RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem;
string a = rt_selecteda.Tag.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`(RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem.Tag.ToString()` means:

1. Take `MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem`
2. Get its `Tag` property
3. Call the Tag's `ToString` method
4. Cast the result as an `RibbonTab`

This fails since a. `MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem` is of type `object` and doesn't have a `Tag` property, and b. even if it had, `ToString` returns a string and you can't cast a string as a `RibbonTab`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example takes everything right if `(RibbonTab)` and treats it as a `RibbonTab`. The second attempts to do the same but fails because `SelectedItem` is of type `Object` so doesn't have a `Tag` property.

You need to cast the SelectedItem, then take the Tag..

```
string ab = ((RibbonTab)MainWindow.Ribbon_Main_Link.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
```